# Dual GPU switching on a MacBook in Windows dual-boot (without using Boot Camp)?

Tags: mac, windows, gpu, dual-boot

I am experimenting with a 2013 MacBook Pro and its capabilities, and have set up a Boot Camp partition. This works quite well with the applications that I need to run on Windows natively which use some dedicated GPU.

However, I found out quickly that Windows running on Boot Camp does not allow for the GPU switching between dedicated and Integrated GPUs, producing uncomfortable heat and draining battery unnecessarily.

I was wondering if anybody had experienced running this kind of technology on Windows in dual-boot with a Mac (without Boot Camp) on a MacBook Pro. And if in that case GPU switching could be supported by the Windows drivers directly?

I have tried to Google this around for some time, but being Boot Camp very prominent, it is very difficult to find good results. I have however found a guide to achieve Windows dual boot, here:

- [Installing Windows 10 on a Mac without Bootcamp](https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/)

I was going to try this if dual GPU switching could be possible. I would be very grateful for any knowledge any of you could share on this topic. Would it be possible to run GPU switching in such a setup?

Comment: Windows 10 does not need Boot-camp at all, and can get access to the hardware on its own. It is Bootcamp that does not support a feature that is instead needed. The question is clear: will Windows drivers work well enough to support dual gpu switching in such a scenario on a MacBook Pro hardware? Your attempt at sarcasm was also a bit inappropriate, besides missing the point.

Comment: Then keep the flame to yourself; nobody is interested in that.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize you are the one that actually asked the question. I will delete my comments. What do you consider Boot Camp to be? The article tells the reader to install the Boot Camp Support Software which contains Windows Boot Camp Installer (`BootCamp.msi`). So the title is wrong. Boot Camp is installed into Windows. Why do you find me pointing this out as sarcasm? –

Comment: The Bootcamp installer, as far as I understand, is used to install the entire set of drivers for the device and to provide the manager to customise the configuration for the Mac hardware. Is this correct? While I can see Bootcamp as a software install within Windows, it seems to me it is more than that, since it is reported to malfunction when managing partitions on disk from within Windows. Also, having Bootcamp as a simple program in Windows does not explain why switching graphics is not available when it is within Mac, and also within Windows on other laptops. Do you have any info on that?